# Highlight of active view in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-2, navigation

Okay, my site is [www.kristianbak.com](http://kristianbak.com).

I have a css class called `activebutton`. I want that to change whenever another View is active. Currently it's merely hard-coded in the HTML (sitemaster).

Anyone with a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could test the current action and if it matches apply a CSS class:

```
<% if (ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == "About") { %>
    ... highlight here
<% } %>
```

Even better I would write a HTML helper to generate the menu:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string text,
    string action, 
    string controller
)
{
    var li = new TagBuilder("li");
    var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
    var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        li.AddCssClass("active");
    }
    li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<ul>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("Home", "Home", "Home") %>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("About Me", "About", "Home") %>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("My Work", "Work", "Home") %>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("Blog", "Index", "Blog") %>
    ...
</ul>
```

This will add the `active` class to the anchor if the current request matches the action and controller of the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks promising! Where should I place the code for that helper method? Inside the CodeBehind of the SiteMaster? And how do I generate all the divs etc. within my `NavButton` class?

Comment: @KristianB, you should place it in a static class. This static class could be located for example in an `Extensions` folder. Just make sure that you bring into scope the namespace into which this static class is defined in the view so that the helper becomes visible. Read here for more information about writing custom HTML helpers: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: You gave me an idea... I just tried using a session variable i called `activeView`. Inside each of my Controllers I set this variable to be the specific View. Like inside Index() method of HomeController it would be `Session["activeView"] = "Home";`. Then I added a bit of code in the codebehind of the Sitemaster to fetch that session variable into a property accessible from the SiteMaster itself. So then it was just a question of if'ing my way through that.

Answer (score 0):

The method I developed thanks to this post:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bdiaz/archive/2010/04/09/handy-asp.net-mvc-2-extension-methods-ndash-where-am-i.aspx

is quite similar. However, the answer has a one big problem. Let's say that we have 3 links:
**Home**, **About** and **Contact**.

We have 4 controllers with default Index actions.
**HomeController**, **AboutController**, **ContactController** and **BiographyController**.

Now, in the **About** page content we have link to **Biography** page, which calls **Index** action in **Biography** controller.

However, clicking on the biography link I would like to maintain About page selected since it is a part of the "About" section.

Most of the solutions that I have found online do not cover this important bit.

Solution I have developed doesn't need to use sessions or some stinky code in Views. All we needed is:

```
 <%= Html.ActionMenuItem("Home", "Index", "Home") %>
 <%= Html.ActionMenuItem("About", "Index", "About") %>
 <%= Html.ActionMenuItem("Contact", "Index", "Contact") %>
```

Since the **solution to this problem** is quite long I have posted it on my blog:

http://arturito.net/2011/08/03/asp-net-mvc-2-highlight-selected-menu-item-on-the-site-master-without-session/