# Best way to add css class to element in razor layout file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a web page with a navigation menu. The current page must be highlighted, which is done by adding a css class. But this menu is defined in the layout page, so how can I add the class to the current menu item?

The only solution I can think of is to use a unique ViewBag property for each menu item, and use that to add the class from the appropriate Action method.
Example:

```
<div class="link @ViewBag.DashboardActive">
    @Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index")
</div>
<div class="link @ViewBag.Item2Active">
    @Html.ActionLink("Item2", "Item2")
</div>
```

etc.

This does the job, but I have a feeling that there is a more elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom helper that will generate those menus and apply a CSS class to the currently selected item. You lay take a look at the [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066862/29407). And here's a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322444/29407) which uses an anchor.

Comment: Cleanest solution I've seen. +1 :)

Comment: thanks, that looks like a nice solution! I'll implement it later today after some other problems are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set ViewBag properties in each action you use is to use `@Html.RenderAction` method.

this is your view:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "MyController", new {selectedItem = "dashboard"}); }
```

this is your menu action:

```
[HttpGet, ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Menu(string selectedItem)
{
    ViewBag.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    return PartialView("Menu");
}
```

in my projects for setting selected menu item i use custom action filter attribute, that I apply to controller/action.